# Avodah Zarah-Is there a Mitzvah in burning excerpts of the christian bible?

Tags: avodah-zarah

Should one burn excerpts of the christian bible or Jews for j booklets?

Comment: Could you [edit] this to say why you think there might be?  Also, are you asserting that these items are *avodah zarah* and asking if burning is the right treatment, or are you also asking if they're A"Z?

Comment: Why would you think this would be a proper thing to do? Elaborate on your question. As Monica Cellio has said so nicely, are you asking if Christianity is Avodah Zarah? Because if you are this is a duplicate.

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/89/is-christianity-avodah-zara?rq=1

Comment: Additionally, why would burning them be any better or worse than just throwing them in the garbage?

Comment: I don't understand the case.  can you give an example?

Comment: you trying to start a pogrom?

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya! Consider learning more about the site from this short [Beginners' Guide](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/a/3887/8775).

Comment: This is a really tactless and inconsiderate question. What would you think if you went to Christianity.SE and somebody asked whether or not they should be burning Talmuds?

Comment: @ShimonbM I'd be interested to read the answers to that. I don't know much about to what extent previous burnings of the Talmud were religiously motivated. (I'm under no illusion that our religions aren't mutually exclusive.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The commandment for the Jews conquering Canaan to destroy *idols* they'd encounter there -- once they acquire them -- does not apply to books.

If you are *given* missionary literature, just throw it in the garbage. (Even if it contains pieces of Tanakh or God's name.) -- As heard from Rabbi Hershel Schachter on a yutorah mp3 of his. I would add -- the best way to do so is quietly, without making a big fuss over it. Otherwise, you just call more attention to it.

Otherwise, if it's not your property, leave it alone!

Comment: The command wasn't only to Jews conquering Canaan.

Comment: Relevant sources demonstrating DoubleAA's point that your claim is spurious can be found here: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/62597/8775.